Lemma's taking value of succeeding theorem
For my notes I'd like to number my lemma's in the following way:
Lemma 1a.
Lemma 1b.
Theorem 1.
Lemma 2a.
Theorem 2.
and so forth.
The following code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{customlemma}{Lemma}
\renewcommand{\thecustomlemma}{\arabic{theorem}\alph{customlemma}}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{customlemma}{theorem}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{customlemma}
\end{customlemma}
\begin{customlemma}
\end{customlemma}
\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}
\begin{customlemma}
\end{customlemma}

gives: 
How can I fix the numeration of the lemma's to equal the succeeding theorem's? So I want the first lemma to be 1 instead of 0 and so on. I have a way to manually do it, but I would prefer it be happening automatically.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{customlemma}{Lemma}
\counterwithin{customlemma}{theorem}
\renewcommand{\thecustomlemma}{\number\numexpr\arabic{theorem}+1\relax\alph{customlemma}}

\begin{document}

\begin{customlemma}
\end{customlemma}
\begin{customlemma}
\end{customlemma}
\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}
\begin{customlemma}
\end{customlemma}
\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}


As @egreg points out, you can replace \number\numexpr\arabic{theorem}+1\relax with \inteval{\value{theorem}+1}.

Perfect thanks! I have tried doing something similar by
\renewcommand{\arabic{\addtocounter{theorem}}\alph{customlemma} but it gave an error.

@JackpotWizard180 The argument of \arabic should be a LaTeX counter name. Anything else is not acceptable.

Yea that is what I thought.. thanks for clarifying! (I'm new here, how do you make the grey area appear after a latex command? In my question I added 4 spaces before it, but I don't know how to do it here or in text.)

@JackpotWizard180 Use two left quotes (`) to enclose the code snippet

\inteval{\value{theorem}+1} is much simpler than \number\numexpr…\relax

@egreg Thanks for this point!
